# need advice about mongodb design

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb, I need an advice on example design that I made below,

**//users**

```
{
  "_id":"ObjectId",
  "name":"String",
  "address":"String",
}
```

**//post**

```
{
  "title":"String",
  "content":"Text",
  "user": {
    "userid":"ObjectId",
  },
  "views": [{
      "userid":"ObjectId"
    },{
      "userid":"ObjectId"
  }],
  "comments":[{
      "userid":"ObjectId",
      "commentText":"Text",
    },
    {
      "userid":"ObjectId",
      "commentText":"Text",
  }],
  "likes": [{
      "userid":"ObjectId"
    },
    {
      "userid":"ObjectId"
  }]
}
```

do i have to put all the fields in users collection into post collection or just with id like i made..? The same question for comments, likes and view. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many views/comments would you expect per post? The document size limit in MongoDB has a limit of 16Mb. With a large number of comments/views, you can easily hit that limit.

Another consideration - concurrency - you'll be updating the same document with every view.

Consider the [Normalized data model, instead of embedded.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/)

Comment: Thank's for the information, for my app, i don't think it will reach 16mb for a document. back to my question, am i right with the design above, or are there things i need to change..?

Comment: If no hard limits are reached - there is no single right or wrong answer here... I would do it differently primarily from the scaling perspective (separating individual comments/views/likes into separate collections aka "normalization"), but that doesn't make your current approach wrong.